# Apache Mod_Rewrite empty query string followed by slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have some super weird URLs I need to redirect.  The original URLs look like this:

```
 server1.com/directory?/tfoo
```

These URLs needs to go here:

```
 server2.com/search~?query=foo
```

I've tried a bunch of different possibilities, but this is what I'm working with right now:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^/t(.*) https://server2.com/search?query=$2 [L,NE,NC]
```

Basically, I thought I would have to look for a blank query string, and then try to move on to grab the value given in the directory structure (foo).  The RewriteCond matches my original URL, but I can't seem to grab the actual query parameter.

I've tried a bunch of things with RegEx to try to ignore the questionmark altogether, but it looks like mod_rewrite only understands the questionmark in the context of a query parameter redirect.

Any advice is hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^/t(.*)$"` ↵ `RewriteRule "^/?directory$" "https://server2.com/search?query=%1" [L,NE,NC]`

Comment: Thanks, @Deadooshka, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadooshka's solution (commented above) worked:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^/t(.*)$"
    RewriteRule "^/?directory$" "https://server2.com/search?query=%1" [L,NE,NC]`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /directory/?/t(.+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://server2.com/search~?query=%1 [NE,L,R]
```